# Nginx - Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .net, http, nginx, networking

I have followed some tutorials on setting up a .Net Core server on Lightsail as well as how to set up SSL for Nginx, resulting in the following 'default' config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 http2 default_server;
    root /var/www/mywebsite/wwwroot;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    root /var/www/mywebsite/wwwroot;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I am currently able to connect to https://mywebsite.com and https://www.mywebsite.com, but when I try to go to the http versions, either nothing is found, or on chrome a file is downloaded with a few strange characters. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seemed to be caused by browsers only supporting HTTP/2 with SSL. This isn't a problem in my case because I am redirecting to the secure site, so changing line 1 of the first server block from

```
listen 80 http2;
```

to

```
listen 80;
```

Solved my problem and now the redirect works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:

    
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com; 
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com; 
    ssl on;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/8289918) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.